# how to extract reviews from iframeurl returned by amazon api in python?

Tags: python, iframe, xpath, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get the `text` content of reviews of a given product in `amazon` using its `api`. But I am not able to work it out. 
Here is what I have:

```
result = api.item_lookup('B00062B6QY', ResponseGroup='Reviews',
     TruncateReviewsAt=256, IncludeReviewsSummary=False)
iframeurl=result.xpath('//*[local-name()="IFrameURL"]/text()')[0].strip()
print iframeurl
reviews=requests.get(iframeurl)
reviews.raise_for_status()
#data = json.loads(reviews.text)
root = ET.fromstring(reviews.text)
print root
```

The output is:

```
http://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=helloworld&alinkCode=xm2&asin=B00062B6QY&atag=welcomehome-20&exp=2014-01-28T19%3A06%3A20Z&summary=0&truncate=256&v=2&sig=HIDDEN%3D
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "amazon_api_new.py", line 36, in <module>
    root = ET.fromstring(reviews.text)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1300, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 867, column 2
```

PS: I have changed the `iframeurl` printed out just to clear the `api  key` details

EDIT: image[image] from `firebug`

Comment: better print and add `reviews.text` to the question

Comment: what `print reviews.text` give you?

Comment: @Guy it gave a huge html-file like object

Comment: `with open('out.html', 'w') as f: f.write(reviews.text)` and open it in text editor to see whats in line 867 or use a browser, then open firebug...

Comment: @Guy I have uploaded an image from firebug

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46172/discussion-between-user1988876-and-guy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using ElementTree, try to load `reviews.text` to [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) like:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(reviews.text), parser)

>>> result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(),
...                         pretty_print=True, method="html")
>>> print(result)
...
```

of course, you can then use [lxml xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) for further parsing

Comment: in my case: I would use broken_html="out.html" from above, correct?

Comment: no need to create a file then, just load html to the parser, see my update

Comment: what should I import for `StringIO`

Comment: I think just `from StringIO import StringIO`

Comment: it is printing html which was similar to the previous one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46173/discussion-between-guy-and-user1988876)